Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
I am using the No proxy & No Vault option trying to create a fabric network by following the commands in below link
https://github.com/hyperledger-bevel/bevel/tree/main/platforms/hyperledger-fabric/charts#without-proxy-or-vault
Getting below error at # Join peer to channel and make it an anchorpeer. How do i rectify this error?
useradmin@100:~/hyperLedgerBevel/bevel/platforms/hyperledger-fabric/charts$ helm install peer0-allchannel ./fabric-channel-join --namespace supplychain-net --set global.vault.type=kubernetes
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition

Request for the help in this regard

Pod is getting auto deleted and we cant see the logs of that pod
